# Running mist command line

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, command-line

Following this example: http://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_mist.html

I'm trying to run mist via command line, but I get: command not found.

I can run geth console, how to do run mist command line? Is there another package I need to brew install / npm down ?

Thanks.

Comment: cd into your mist installation folder, run it from there.

Comment: for mac follow these instructions
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28421/3498

Answer (score 0):

I use Mac and this works for me

```
/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc 127.0.0.1:8545
```

You may also want to go through the suggestions here in a similar question
[connect ethereum wallet(or mist) to to ethereum local private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21336/connect-ethereum-walletor-mist-to-to-ethereum-local-private-network/56954#56954)