# connect ethereum wallet(or mist) to to ethereum local private network

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain, network

I would like to create a private network for test. And I would like to connect to this private network from commandline client or Ethereum wallet/mint.

I have created a private network as below.

```
geth --datadir=./chaindata init genesis.json
```

The content of genesis.json is [genesis.json](https://github.com/tomw1808/truffle_eth_class2/blob/master/s01/genesis.json)

Afterwards, I have started private network with following commands. (I have tried both of these commands seperately)

```
geth --datadir=./chaindata 
geth --datadir=./chaindata --networkid 15
```

Afterwards, I have opened another terminal and try to connect running private network. But it does not connect.

```
geth attach
```

I have realised it is trying to connect default geth.ipc which is not running and I have send the running private network's geth.ipc as parameter and I is solved.

```
geth attach ~/chaindata/geth.ipc
```

But, I could not change the default geth.ipc for Mist or Ethereum Wallet. How can I connect Ethereum Wallet/Mist to private network?

Ethereum Wallet/Mist error message during startup

```
Couldn't connect to node? See the logs for more:
...
...
INFO [07-16|15:47:51] Starting P2P networking 
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind:   address already in use
```

Comment: it seems running geth like this: geth --datadir=./chaindata --networkid 15 --ipcpath /Users/{user-name}/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc

Comment: I have found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661738/how-do-i-connect-to-a-private-network-from-ethereum-wallet

Answer (score 5):

to start a local test network you can now use

> geth --dev

once you do, take note of where it has actually created it by reading the line:

> IPC endpoint opened: /var/folders/y1/jynwfrwj411bxck8whqgcbr00000gq/T/ethereum_dev_mode/geth.ipc

Then to have MIST connect to the private network type this in your terminal (MAC version)

> open -a /Applications/Mist.app --args --rpc /var/folders/y1/jynwfrwj411bxck8whqgcbr00000gq/T/ethereum_dev_mode/geth.ipc

Comment: Is this the only way to do it in Terminal? Could you do `geth --datadir ./chaindata` then something like `geth attach /var/folders/2k/p756_j5x0x5fqplwrq74j1sh0000gn/T/geth.ipc`? Is `geth --dev` the only way to start the test network? Btw, test network refers to your own private 80GB node correct?

Answer (score 3):

you can open the Mist using the following command:

```
open -a /Applications/Mist.app --args --rpcport "8001" --rpc  <node path>/geth.ipc
```

Please just replace the location of the mist.app if it's different than yours, and change the port if you are using different port.

Answer (score 1):

Creation of the blockchain looks fine.

Be sure that Mist is closed.

Then start a geth node with

`geth --datadir ./chaindata`

open a new console and attach a Javascript Console with

`geth attach`

Then start the Mist wallet and you should be connected to your private network.

Comment: Has anyone confirmed this method? It does not work for me. The above method by b25 works for me.  `geth --datadir ./chaindata` does not start a test network. It only starts a node. You could do `geth attach /var/folders/2k/p756_j5x0x5fqplwrq74j1sh0000gn/T/geth.ipc` but that won't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try just building against the test network using `npm install -g ethereum-testrpc`, then deploy your code and test on livenet. You would have to build Mist/EWalet against test net in order to test it. Check out https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/blob/master/README.md for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To start Mist is actually: /Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist  --rpc 127.0.0.1:8501